# ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateSolidColorBrush() crash

Tags: crash, direct2d

I need to create ID2D1DCRenderTarget, because I need compability with GDI. I do it with the following code:

```
ID2D1Factory* factory;
ID2D1DCRenderTarget* target;
ID2D1SolidColorBrush* brush;

using namespace D2D1;
D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &factory);

D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES rtp = RenderTargetProperties();
rtp.usage = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_GDI_COMPATIBLE;

factory->CreateDCRenderTarget(&rtp, &target);

target->CreateSolidColorBrush(ColorF(ColorF::White), &brush);
```

Program crashes in the last line. But when I try to similarily create ID2D1HwndRenderTarget everything works fine. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I checked something more and it appears that any of ID2D1DCRenderTarget functions I'd try to call in place of CreateSolidColorBrush() crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I checked it, it appears that problem is with RenderTargetProperties(), beacuse if D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES is filled for example like that:

```
D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES rtp = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT,
    D2D1::PixelFormat(
        DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
        D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
    0,
    0,
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE,
    D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_DEFAULT
    );
```

everything works.